# Which is a better linq query? .Where(crit).FirstOrDefault() or .Where(someCrit).FirstOrDefault(someOtherCrit)?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

Looking to do a bit of refactoring... Using NHibernate I have this query currently

```
 public Widget FindByCode(string code)
 {
  return 
             _session
                 .Query<Widget>()
                 .Where(w => !w.IsDeleted)
                 .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Code == code);
  }
```

I was thinking of using this

```
public Widget FindByCode(string code)
 {
  return 
             _session
                 .Query<Widget>()
                 .Where(w => !w.IsDeleted && w.Code == code)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

Is either one any better than the other? Any tips, links, or code is always appreciated. 
Cheers!

Comment: They both _should_ translate to the same expression and therefore the same sql, but the second one looks more readable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In linq2objects or linq2sql you can write just a FirstOrDefault like this:

```
public Widget FindByCode(string code)
 {
  return 
             _session
                 .Query<Widget>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(w => !w.IsDeleted && w.Code == code);
  }
```

Not sure about NHibernate, but but probably works. And you can always check the generated sql with NHProf, or regular sql profiler.

Answer (score 3):

It seems confusing to me to split the predicate into two chunks.  I'd keep the "filtering" code in one place and either put it all in `.Where` (your second example) or all in `.FirstOrDefault`.  The latter option is more concise and uses fewer operators, so is generally ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is better since it will only do one projection based on both criterias. The first one will do a first projection based on the first criteria and then apply a second projection based on the second criteria.
I would recommend using the second approach.